# AOAGs State Report

Tags: sql-server-2014, powershell

Some unwanted columns are produced while I run this script.How can I get rid of them ? Please let me know my misses and thanks.

```
[System.Reflection.Assembly]::LoadWithPartialName(“Microsoft.SqlServer.Smo”) | Out-Null 
$query = "SELECT node_name
,group_name
,role_desc
,operational_state_desc
,synchronization_health_desc
FROM sys.dm_hadr_availability_replica_cluster_nodes AS cn
LEFT JOIN sys.dm_hadr_availability_replica_cluster_states AS cs
    ON cn.replica_server_name = cs.replica_server_name
INNER JOIN sys.dm_hadr_availability_replica_states AS rs 
    ON cs.replica_id = rs.replica_id "

$instance = @('Server1', 'Server2','Server3', 'Server4')
ForEach($inst in $instance) 
{
    $Result=Invoke-Sqlcmd -Query $query -ServerInstance $inst | ConvertTo-Html | Out-File 'C:\TEMP\RESULT.HTM' -Append |Ft -Autosize
}
```

[image]

[image]

Answer (score 2, accepted):

As it is now, your script overwrites the contents of the `result.htm` output file at every iteration.

If you want to append to the output file, move the Out-File call inside the loop and use the `-Append` parameter.

Comment: ,thank you and it worked and I have updated my question.Can you please see my output (I removed server names and AG Group name)  and I can see some extra columns coming in like rowstate table,haserros,itemarray.how can I get rid of them ? and this I am running in remote server,can you please tell me if any way I can execute the file from VDI machine from which we remote all the machines in the script.

Comment: You can use `| Select col1, col2, ... colN` to choose which columns to include.

Comment: Thank you @spaghettidba,this works.but I am getting additional top of output System.Data_DataRow System.DataRow System_Data_DataRow.I mentioned in the question new updated pic of my output.Please let me know how to remove it and can I make the output clearly as a table.

Comment: @SQLBoy I don't see your code, I can't help you. Want to move this conversation to chat?

Comment: It is working,thank you @spaghettidba.Thanks for your time

Answer (score 1):

Just offering up another option to use the T-SQL. [DbaTools PowerShell module](https://github.com/sqlcollaborative/dbatools) (developed/maintained by folks in SQL Server Community) will have a new command added in October release: `Get-DbaAvailabilityGroup`.

An example detailed output:
[image]

If you want to see the code I wrote for this command you can find that on [GitHub under my fork of the repo here](https://github.com/wsmelton/dbatools/blob/NewCommand-Get-DbaAvailabilityGroup/functions/Get-DbaAvailabilityGroup.ps1).

Comment: Hi @Shawn, Thanks for sharing and it is very helpful .Will try it on to our in place process.